# how to extract from a numpy array all the zero and non zero values in a new array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Given a numpy array:

```
arr = [0,0,0,0,0,2,0]
```

How can I extract in a new array all the zero elements:

```
new_arr = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

And the non zero elements:

```
new_arr_2 = [2]
```

I tried by transforming the array into a list and with a for loop. Also, I tried with:

```
np.argwhere(arr == 0).ravel()
```

However, I am just getting the indices. Any idea of how to extract zero, and non zero, or even specific number values with numpy?

Comment: Just use `arr[arr==0]` and `arr[arr!=0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), you can get the indices of items satisfying your condition and get the corresponding value:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,2,0])

new_arr_0 = arr[np.where(arr==0)]
new_arr_no_0 = arr[np.where(arr!=0)]
```

Of course, as suggested by @Sheldore and @DeveshKumarSingh you can simply go with:

```
new_arr_0 = arr[arr==0]
new_arr_no_0 = arr[arr!=0]
```

For small arrays you should not find large differences in terms of computational speed.

Comment: what if I want to extract all the `2` in my array?

Comment: Then, `new_arr_2 = arr[np.where(arr==2)]`

Comment: @anon: Just use `arr[arr==2]`

Answer (score -1):

You can use list comprehensions instead of using numpy :

```py
arr = [0,0,0,0,0,2,0]
new_arr = [a for a in arr if a == 0]
new_arr_no_zero = [a for a in arr if a != 0]
```